# SQL Server tool that allows navigating through key relationships

Tags: sql

Does anyone have a knowledge of a tool that allows to **navigate over reliationships** between entities in **sql server database?** 
I want to be able to list all rows in a table and then (for selected row) jump to all rows that match (in a context of relation between tables).
The same thing can be done in **LINQ to SQL** by querying **navigation properties** but it's not convinient to do this in code all the time.
I tried to use **LINQPad** but query results are not interactive in this way - again it can be done in code.

Thanks for answers in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Try PL/SQL Developer, It should be working as you expect.

**For eg:** If we view a table, the 1st few rows of the table will be shown.

Then when you want to go to a child table or parent table from that. You had 2 types of hierarchy button for each.

[image: sql developer img]

The button circled in image was one of them. And this one particularly was for finding child references from this table.

On clicking it you will be show you the table references from this table using the foreign key relation ship. And on selecting one of them it will change the sql query to filter out with the table and column you selected.

The application was a bit different from other tools out in market, but once you got to know how to use it.

I think this is their [home page](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html)

Comment: oops! don't know. I used on oracle only. Will have to check